# How to avoid 24 IF statements option SQL query parameters

Tags: php, sql

There are 4 search parameters that the user can input to perform this sql search but all of them are optional.

The parameters are user, book_id, start and length (start and length form a range, using the index of the table in the database, i.e startin looking at row index 5 and return my 4 records)

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
$book_id = $_GET['book_id'];
$start = $_GET['start'];
Slength = $_GET['length'];
```

//Look for the length of items, ending at the index -1

```
$end = $start + $length -1;
```

With 4 optional search parameters there are 24 different SQL query statmenetes that could be executed?

How can avoid writing 24 IF statements? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why 24?

You can do it with only 4:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1';
if ($user) {
    $sql .= " AND user = '{$user}'"
}
if ($book_id) {
    $sql .= " AND book_id = '{$book_id}'"
}
//... and so on
```

This is a simple solution. For more complex things, you'd have to create a query builder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one statement and add the possibility for `null`in that variables

```
select * from your_table
where (username = $user or $user is null)
and (book_id = $book_id or $book_id is null)
and (start = $start or $start is null)
and (end = $start + $length - 1 or $length is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
$fields = array("user", "book_id", "start", "length");

foreach($fields as $field){
    if(array_key_exists($field, $_GET) && strlen($_GET[$field]) {
        // your bit of SQL stuff here ...
    }
}
```

Though that's not really a huge improvement, as it makes the code a lot harder to read.

Can you give me an example of what the final SQL should look like?

Regards,
Phil,

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query and some conditional code, like so:

```
$query =<<<END_QUERY
        SELECT * 
        FROM table
        WHERE (user LIKE '%$user%' OR book_id = $book_id)
END_QUERY;

if($start && $end)
    $query .= "AND (id BETWEEN $start AND $end)";
elseif($start)
    $query .= "AND (id >= $start)";
elseif($end)
    $query .= "AND (id <= $end)";
```